# getBoundingClientRect() rotated object

Tags: javascript, rotation

I have a rectangular SVG object which is rotated via transform="rotate(45,0,0)". Using getBoundingClientRect() on the object gives the width and height of the bounding box which is not correct with the rotation.

I have searched and tried many calculations to get the original width and height taking off the rotation.

```
var rectangle = object.getBoundingClientRect()
var width = Math.sin(radian) * rectangle.height + Math.cos(radian) * rectangle.width
var height = Math.sin(radian) * rectangle.width + Math.cos(radian) * rectangle.height
```

And many other variations on this i have found, any help on the correct formula to use would be great. All i have is the values from getBoundingClientRect() and the radian.

Comment: What is your intended pivot point? The center of the rectangle or the bottom left corner?

Comment: center of the rectangle

Comment: spent hours on this just use var rectangle = object.getBBox() then no need for any calculations...